# Retrospectively Link a PBI to a Commit in Azure Devops

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-boards

I am aware you can use the `#XXX` format as part of a commit message to link the commit to a PBI but is there a way to do this after the commit has been pushed?

Our devs occasionally forget to prefix the number with # or just forget to link completely and being able to track commits via a PBI is really useful.

Comment: Do you want to link the commit with the prefix or linking without it is also good?

Comment: I just want a way where i can link an existing PBI with an existing commit

Comment: It's possible easily, check my answer :)

Comment: @CeejeeB, did the answer solve your issue?  You can mark the answer which is benefit to other communities who has the same issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the PBI, in the right tabs click on the "links" tab:

[image]

Click on add link -> existing item:

[image]

In the link type choose "Commit", enter the commit id (or search it in the `...`) and click ok:

[image]